# Stored procedure fails (probably due to nested transactions/commits)

Tags: sql-server

I get the following error message when executing a stored procedure:

> [SQLSTATE 25000] (Error 3902)
>   The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

This is what my stored procedure looks like:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [InputData].[Update_eFile_Cesar]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @CommNr nvarchar(10);
    Declare @VSBOrderKey int;
    Declare @CesarOrderKey int;
    Declare @PK_Checklist int;
    Declare @OLD_PreOrder nvarchar(20);
    Declare @NEW_PreOrder nvarchar(20);

    select ons.CommissionNumber, binary_checksum(co.OrderDate,co.[NationalType],co.[CustomerNumber],co.[Firstname],co.[Surname],co.[CompanyName],co.[LeasingCompanyNumber]
                    ,co.[LeasingCompanyName],co.[FleetNumber],co.[FleetNumberNational],co.[ContractSignOffDate],co.[VehicleUsage],co.[OrderStatus]
                    ,co.[EstimatedDeliveryDate],co.[DeliveryDate],co.[DestinationKey],co.[FinalProductionDate],co.[ProductionDecade],co.[ChassisNumber]
                    ,co.[VehicleDescription],ons.PreOrderNumber)  AS 'CheckSumSAM',ons.PreOrderNumber AS 'OLD_PreOrder', co.PK_OrderCesar AS 'CesarOrderKey',
                    binary_checksum(o.OrderDate, v.NationalType, c.CustomerNumber, c.FirstName, c.Surname, c.CompanyName, c.LeasingCompanyNumber
                    , c.LeasingCompanyName, c.FleetNumber,c.FleetNumberNational, c.ContractSignOffDate, o.VehicleUsage, o.OrderStatus
                    , o.EstimatedDeliveryDate, o.DeliveryDate, o.DestinationKey, o.FinalProductionDate
                    ,o.ProductionDecade, v.ChassisNumber, v.VehicleDescription, o.PreOrderNumber) AS 'CheckSumLDS',
                    o.PreOrderNumber AS 'NEW_PreOrder' into #temptable2
        FROM [sam].[CesarOrders] co 
        INNER JOIN [sam].[VehicleFiles] vf on co.PK_OrderCesar = vf.FK_OrderCesar
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrderNumbers] ons on vf.PK_VehicleFile = ons.FK_VehicleFile
        INNER JOIN [LDS_XML].[LDS].[Orders] o on ons.CommissionNumber = o.FactoryOrderNumber
        LEFT JOIN [LDS_XML].[LDS].[Vehicles] v on o.OrderId = v.OrderId
        LEFT JOIN [LDS_XML].[LDS].[Customers] c on o.OrderId = c.OrderId
        --where ons.CommissionNumber = '0651312526'

    Declare Akte_Update_Tabelle CURSOR FOR 
        Select CommissionNumber, OLD_PreOrder, NEW_PreOrder, CesarOrderKey 
        from #temptable2 
        where CheckSumSAM <> CheckSumLDS

    OPEN Akte_Update_Tabelle;

    Fetch next from Akte_Update_Tabelle into @CommNr, @OLD_PreOrder, @NEW_PreOrder, @CesarOrderKey;

    while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    Begin
        BEGIN TRAN
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
---- OrderCesar Update
---------------------------------------------------------------
--Select 'In der Schleife' as Status, @CommNr as CommNumber, @CesarOrderKey as CESARKey
UPDATE [SAM].[CesarOrders]
   SET [UpdateDate] = getdate()
      ,[OrderDate] = o.OrderDate
      ,[NationalType] = v.NationalType
      ,[CustomerNumber] = c.CustomerNumber
      ,[Firstname] = c.FirstName
      ,[Surname] = c.Surname
      ,[CompanyName] = c.CompanyName
      ,[LeasingCompanyNumber] = c.LeasingCompanyNumber
      ,[LeasingCompanyName] = c.LeasingCompanyName
      ,[FleetNumber] = c.FleetNumber
      ,[FleetNumberNational] = c.FleetNumberNational
      ,[ContractSignOffDate] = c.ContractSignOffDate
      ,[VehicleUsage] = o.VehicleUsage
      ,[OrderStatus] = o.OrderStatus
      ,[EstimatedDeliveryDate] = o.EstimatedDeliveryDate
      ,[DeliveryDate] = o.DeliveryDate
      ,[DestinationKey] = o.DestinationKey
      ,[FinalProductionDate] = o.FinalProductionDate
      ,[ProductionDecade] = o.ProductionDecade
      ,[ChassisNumber] = v.ChassisNumber
      ,[VehicleDescription] = v.VehicleDescription
 FROM [sam].[CesarOrders] co 
 inner join [sam].[VehicleFiles] vf on co.PK_OrderCesar = vf.FK_OrderCesar
 inner join [dbo].[OrderNumbers] ons on vf.PK_VehicleFile = ons.FK_VehicleFile
 inner join [LDS_XML].[LDS].[Orders] o on ons.CommissionNumber = o.FactoryOrderNumber
 left join [LDS_XML].[LDS].[Vehicles] v on o.OrderId = v.OrderId
 left join [LDS_XML].[LDS].[Customers] c on o.OrderId = c.OrderId
 WHERE PK_OrderCesar = @CesarOrderKey 

 -----------------------------------------------------------------
------ Update VehicleFiles mit vorhandener Checkliste oder Calculation
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Noch keine Checkliste vorhanden
IF @OLD_PreOrder is NULL and @NEW_PreOrder is not NULL
BEGIN
--Select 'Update'
Update [dbo].[OrderNumbers]
SET [PreOrderNumber] = @NEW_PreOrder
    where [CommissionNumber] = @CommNr
END

-- Für Kontingentfahrzeuge brauchen wir eine Sonderroutine. Zum Zeitpunkt des Anlegens der Checkliste ist dem Verkäufer nur die PreOrder bekannt. Die Checkliste legt
-- einen Datensatz an, der etwa so aussieht: 

--PK_OrderNumber    FK_Checklist    FK_VehicleFile  PreOrderNumber  CommissionNumber    
--56630             2126            NULL            000007129370    NULL        

-- Die PreOrderNummer der umgewidmeten Kommissionsnummern wird erst NACH Anlage der Checkliste vergeben und läuft dann 1 Tag später in OrderNumbers ein. 
-- D.h. es werden zwangsläufig zwei Zeilen angelegt, da die folgende Zeile (allerdings ohne die PreOrderNummer) bereits Wochen oder Monate vor der Checkliste existiert (da Kontingent)

--PK_OrderNumber    FK_Checklist    FK_VehicleFile  PreOrderNumber  CommissionNumber    
--56107             NULL            4132            000007129370    0951380877      

-- Wir brauchen nun eine Routine, die die FK_Checklist der ersten Zeile in die zweite Zeile umhängt:

if ( Select Count(*) from OrderNumbers where PreOrderNumber = @NEW_PreOrder) = 2
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    Declare @rowWithVehicleID int = (select PK_OrderNumber from OrderNumbers where PreOrderNumber = @NEW_PreOrder AND FK_VehicleFile IS NOT NULL)
    Declare @rowWithChecklistID int = (select PK_OrderNumber from OrderNumbers where PreOrderNumber = @NEW_PreOrder AND FK_Checklist IS NOT NULL)
    Declare @FK_CL int = (select FK_Checklist from OrderNumbers where PK_OrderNumber = @rowWithChecklistID)
        -- 1. Checkliste abhängen
       UPDATE dbo.OrderNumbers 
       SET FK_Checklist = NULL WHERE PK_OrderNumber = @rowWithChecklistID;  

       -- 2. Checkliste mit dem richtigen Datensatz verknüpfen
       UPDATE dbo.OrderNumbers 
       SET FK_Checklist = @FK_CL WHERE PK_OrderNumber = @rowWithVehicleID
       -- 3. Löschen des nun nicht mehr benötigten Datensatzes
       DELETE FROM dbo.OrderNumbers WHERE PK_OrderNumber = @rowWithChecklistID
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN --RollBack in case of Error
END CATCH

-- PreOrder bereits vorhanden aber die Neue ist unterschiedlich zur Alten
IF @OLD_PreOrder is not NULL and @OLD_PreOrder <> @NEW_PreOrder
BEGIN
--Select 'Update PreOrder', @CommNr as KomNummer, @OLD_PreOrder as AltePreOrder, @NEW_PreOrder As NeuePreOrder
Update [dbo].[OrderNumbers]
Set [PreOrderNumber]  = @NEW_PreOrder
Where [CommissionNumber] = @CommNr
END

COMMIT TRAN

    Fetch next from Akte_Update_Tabelle into @CommNr, @OLD_PreOrder, @NEW_PreOrder, @CesarOrderKey

END
CLOSE Akte_Update_Tabelle;
DEALLOCATE Akte_Update_Tabelle;

drop table #temptable2

END
```

The Sp was running just fine before I added the try-catch block. I strongly believe, that this is where the error occurs. I also believe that it's the nested BEGIN TRAN / COMMIT that causes this error but I don't know how to do this in a better way. Maybe just omit the try catch entirely? Or just use the try/catch without a specific transaction?

Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a nested transaction in SQL Server](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/), that's your problem.

Comment: My advice would be to read [this](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) and the more detailed follow-up linked there. It's a lot, but error handling in T-SQL is such a big and confusing topic that it's worth having the details. Doubly so if you start mixing in awful stuff like cursors. To a first approximation, `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is nearly always your friend. (Plus what Larnu said: nesting transactions brings no benefit as SQL Server just sorts of pretends this works, and instead it just adds more complication since a single failure is still deadly.)

Comment: There are a couple of major issues other than using nested transaction going on here. First is this references a temp table which isn't defined in this procedure. While this does work it means this procedure is not a complete procedure as it can't run on its own. Second, and the biggest issue here by far imho, is that you are using cursors to run update statements. The whole thing reads like an application instead of data manipulation.

Comment: @Larnu: I read this article the other day, that's why my first thought was that my SP fails because of the "nested" commit which not only commits the stuff that happens between my 2nd BEGIN TRAN and the following Commit but everything since the first BEGIN TRAN. When the second commit at the end of the script fires, there is no active TRAN anymore because both TRANS were already committed by the first commit. I think I will have to test removing the inner BEGIN TRAN / Commit combo.